# All items in AutoCompleteTextView (Spinner)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, spinner, autocompletetextview

Hi  I ve got a problem with my Spinner and AutocompleteTextView. 
Now my spinner displays only items that begin with for example the letter "k".I would like to dsiplay all items from the list. Is it possible?
Below is my MainActivity and picture of my problem.

Thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private Spinner fromSpinner, toSpinner;
private EditText fromEditText, toEditText;
private AutoCompleteTextView autoComplete;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    autoComplete = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.szukanie);
    autoComplete.setThreshold(0);


    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.units, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    fromSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_from);
    toSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_to);

    fromSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    toSpinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    fromEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_from);
    toEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText_to);


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
    toolbar.setTitleTextColor(Color.YELLOW);
    autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
```

[this shows only "k"items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/00t43.png)

Comment: What is the value of `R.array.units`

Comment: The values are items, contained in strings.xml. For example:<string-array name="units"><item>kg</item></string-array></resources>